# ED137 SIP & RTP (VoIP) for Air Traffic Control Use with Cisco CUBE

Tags: cisco, voip, sip, rtp

I am working with an air traffic control client who is using a variant of SIP called ED137.

There are 2 main uses, Ground to Ground (basically telephone calls) and Air to Ground to Air (radio traffic to flights).

GG is straight forward enough, any extra info (ED137 elements) is contained in the SIP headers and in all essence is the same as a standard SIP call.

AGA however is different. The radios sit waiting for a SIP connection, so the centre instigates it. There is additional SIP additional header info for R2S timers which appear to transit the CUBE OK, and then it sets up a continuous RTP stream, where the timer info is contained in RTP packets with extended headers.

So essentially, when there is no voice traffic, there is still RTP packets communicating, but with these timers only.... these are identified as payload type 123 (R2S) within the RTP element.

when there is voice traffic is sent, depending on the direction (TX =PTT or RX = Squelch), a flag is changed in the RTP extended header and the payload type changes to 0 (G711 U law).

I have dial peers and global settings setup which work fine for the ground to ground element, codec transparent, pass all unsupported headers, no VAD etc...

But for the air to ground to air stuff, the same dial peers appear to not like the RTP extended header elements. It stops the R2S timers returning, so I get a bouncing connection as the radios times out, kill the connections, then the centre tries to re-establish.

The CUBE doesn't allow any of the extended header RTP packets to transit correctly, which to me appears to be the crux of the issue.

Anyone worked with ED137 AGA stuff that can help, or any advice on dealing with extended RTP headers or a change in payload type (from 123 to 0 etc....)?

Is there specific setting required to allow RTP packets with extended headers through a Cisco CUBE?